# MiniBatchKMeans gives different centroids after subsequent iterations

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using the `MiniBatchKMeans` model from the `sklearn.cluster` module in anaconda. I am clustering a data-set that contains approximately 75,000 points. It looks something like this:

`data = np.array([8,3,1,17,5,21,1,7,1,26,323,16,2334,4,2,67,30,2936,2,16,12,28,1,4,190...])`

I fit the data using the process below.

`from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(batch_size=100)
kmeans.fit(data.reshape(-1,1)`

This is all well and okay, and I proceed to find the centroids of the data:

`centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
print centroids`

Which gives me the following output:

`array([[   13.09716569],
       [ 2908.30379747],
       [   46.05089228],
       [  725.83453237],
       [   95.39868475],
       [ 1508.38356164],
       [  175.48099948],
       [  350.76287263]])`

But, when I run the process again, using the same data, I get different values for the centroids, such as this:

`array([[   29.63143489],
       [ 1766.7244898 ],
       [  171.04417206],
       [ 2873.70454545],
       [   70.05295277],
       [ 1074.50387597],
       [  501.36134454],
       [    8.30600975]])`

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Yeah you seem to be using 75000 int32s, which is only 300 kb, so why aren't you just using regular k-means

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are experiencing probably has to do with the under the hood implementation of k-means clustering that you are using. k-means clustering is an NP-hard problem, so all the implementations out there are heuristic methods. What this means practically is that for a given seed, it will converge toward a local optima that isn't necessarily consistent across multiple seeds.

Comment: Meaning what? I run `fit()` several times, pair like values, and take an average to get the truest values for the centroids?

Comment: Do not take this advice as meaningful, because I don't remember much of this stuff, but I think using any given local optima is more useful that the mean centroid, because local optima do not necessarily occur in equal distributions around the global optimum. For anything you're doing, any given set of centroids should be close enough to optimal. If you're looking for consistency, I would specify the random_state parameter, so you get the same set of centroids each execution

Comment: If you're really going for perfection at the cost of processing power, it might be valuable to run it multiple times and decide on a solution which seems to be most optimal, if you can implement some way to do that. It is almost certainly not worth the trouble, though.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on what mini-batch k-means is.

It will never even *converge*. Do one more iteration, the result will change *again*.

It is design for data sets so huge you cannot load them into memory at once. So you load a batch, pretend this were the full data set, do one iterarion. Repeat woth the next batch. If your batches are large enough and random, then the result will be "close enough" to be usable. While itjs never optimal.

Thus:

1. the minibatch results are even more random than regular k-means results. They change every iteration.
2. if you can load your data into memory, don't use minibatch. Instead use a fast k-means implementation. (most are surprisingly slow).

P.S. on one-dimensional data, *sort* your data set and then use an algorithm that benefits from the sorting instead of k-means.