# Can Apache K Means WSSSE increase with some K?

Tags: apache-spark, k-means

I am trying to see if there is point in the "elbow graph" which would help me to choose K in K means algorithm

However, I notice that the WSSSE sometimes increases as K increases. I was under the assumption that WSSSE would always decrease as K increases. I attach a picture showing this along with the Pyspark code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38arI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which is guaranteed is that once you've reached k==n you'll get a WSSSE of zero because each point directly lies on a cluster centroid, bringing SSE to zero for each point and therefore WSSSE as well. The reason why your function is non-convex is that k-means uses random initialization of cluster centroids (seeds) and the optimization function of k-means is non-deterministic with respect to the initial cluster centroid distribution (as this problem is NP-Hard). Therefore you can end up in a lower local optima on different runs. Here another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751364/minibatchkmeans-gives-different-centroids-after-subsequent-iterations) on this topic.